# Apagar dados Mysql

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma tabela com uma quantidade grande de dados (380 milhões).
Preciso apagar os dados antigos que não tem mais utilidade no sistema.
Estou gerando o backup por precaução.

Qual a melhor forma de apagar?

- Apagar com um delete restringindo a partir de qual data ?
- Apagar pouco a pouco 50k em 50k ?
- Apagar pouco a pouco 1k em 1k ?
- Ou alguma outra forma ?

Estou fazendo de 50k em 50k porém é bastante demorado.
Qual a melhor solução visando agilidade?

Comment: Se você vai limpar a tabela, acredito que a melhor opção seria um `DROP`, depois recriá-la. Mas vamos ver a opinião dos professores! rs +1

Comment: Na verdade não vou limpar, apenas apagar registros antigos

Comment: Na sua tabela tem o campo data ? poste a foto aqui dos campos

Comment: [Excluindo grandes volumes de dados](https://imasters.com.br/banco-de-dados/excluindo-grandes-volumes-de-dados)

Comment: Eu utilizaria a primeira opção

Comment: @rbz Justamente oq estou fazendo, porém de qlq forma a demora é significativa. Gostaria de uma forma que fosse mais ágil

Comment: @PedroAugusto Aí vai do seu cenário. Exemplo: Vamos supor que "copiar" o registro seja 1.5x do tempo do "excluir". Então se dos 380 milhões de registros você precisa excluir "metade", então compensa realmente o script com o loop. Supondo que, você precisa excluir 90%, então você poderia criar uma tabela igual, migrar os 10% dos registros que quer manter, dar um DROP nessa tabela, e altera o nome da copiada.

Comment: Talvez seja mais rapido criar uma tabela temporaria com os dados que você quer manter. Dropar a tabela antiga, recria-la e inserir novamente os dados a partir da tabela temporaria,

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo Basicamente o que eu disse, mas sem perder tempo voltando os dados. Mas claro, depende a proporção que ele precisa manter/excluir...

Comment: Abriu minha cabeça isso que comentaram. Vou aplicar. Obg

Comment: Se for usar a opção de salvar os dados em uma tabela temporaria você não precisa dropar e recriar, você pode truncar a tabela que em tese é a mesma coisa.

Comment: Recomendo a fazer o delete por dia, e cuidado para não encher o transaction log

Answer (score -1):

Crie um índice com a coluna data, após isso crie uma procedure com o comando "delete from tabela where data > '0000-00-00'" e, enfim, coloque um evento para chamar essa procedure (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html). Daí basta esperar pela execução.

Comment: Carlos, o evento não bloqueia a tabela? Dê um exemplo simples do evento para poder vermos. Pontue os principais detalhes. Assim a resposta fica completa! ✌️

Comment: Fique tranquilo pois o evento não dá lock na tabela; é apenas uma execução em background! Vamos imaginar que você tem uma tabela com dados de vendas de 20 anos atrás chamado "tb_sistema_fatura" com as colunas: id, nome do cliente, valor total e data de venda. Crie um índice para a data de vendas para ajudar na execução do comando "delete ... where": CREATE INDEX idx_sistema_fatura ON schema.idx_sistema_fatura(data de venda) USING BTREE.

Comment: Com o índice criado... agora você cria um evento para fazer a deleção: CREATE EVENT delecao ON SCHEDULE AT '2018-08-24 00:00:00'  DO delete from schema.idx_sistema_fatura where data de venda < '2010-01-01'. Assim, você pode fazer outras coisas, enquanto o processo roda em backgound.

Comment: Po cara, bacana esses detalhes... Daria para você fazer uma baita resposta bem formulada, com detalhes, links para maiores consultas, etc. ✌️